# Linking error during mex compilation

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I wrote a c++ program which uses the library yaml-cpp. I built it myself using cmake and the library is now located as /usr/local/lib/libyaml-cpp.a .
In my eclipse project, building the program works fine.

For testing the program output in matlab, I also embedded the program into a mex wrapper. 
I try to compile the following mex command:

```
prefix = '../../Synthesizer/src/'; 
mex ('-g', '../mex/synth_process_mex.cpp', [prefix 'test/TestClient.cpp'], [prefix 'Synth.cpp'], ...
    [prefix 'DataReader.cpp'], [prefix 'StochasticDataReader.cpp'], [prefix 'GlobalMath.cpp'],...
    [prefix 'Sinusoid.cpp'], [prefix 'Interpolator.cpp'], [prefix 'OSCReceiver.cpp'],...
    [prefix 'Voice.cpp'], '-lyaml-cpp');
```

This used to work fine, until I started using the yaml-cpp library. Now, Matlab returns the following error message:

```
Error using mex
/usr/bin/ld: //usr/local/lib/libyaml-cpp.a(parse.cpp.o): Die Umlagerung von
//usr/local/lib/libyaml-cpp.a: error adding symbols: Ungültiger Wert
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can anybody help me with that? Sorry, I didn't know how to change the language of the compiler message.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that the problem was, that I used a statically library version of yaml-cpp. I changed to a shared library, libyaml-cpp.so and everthing works now.